# Non Orthogonal Multiple Acess and Channel Quality Indicator

Tags: telecommunication, wireless-communication

As we know in a 4G network, the LTE give us a correlation about the SNR of user and the data rate of the user. This correlation is usually a table called Channel Quality Indicator (CQI) which is found in C[hannel Quality Indicator Feedback in Long Term Evolution(LTE) System](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d738/479b73a487b1308ba18ac9a4d2e2a8df596a.pdf).

My question:  Is there something similar like -LTE CQI- in 5G networks in NOMA(Non Orthogonal Multiple Access)?